# Modal takes ~30 seconds to open

Tags: reactjs, performance, redux-form, redux-saga, semantic-ui-react

I have a modal in my application that sometimes takes ~30 seconds to open. The chrome devtools profiler shows that the react components finish rendering, then there is a long gap where there is no javascript code reported to be running and then the modal becomes visible on the screen. During this empty gap, the profiler only shows a long Animation happening in the Interactions section.

What can I do to make the modal open faster? What is the browser doing during this Animation?

**Information about the app**

1. Uses react + redux
2. Uses redux-saga for side effects
3. Uses redux-form for form management
4. Uses semantic-ui-react UI components
5. Uses styled-components for CSS

**Information about the modal**

1. There is an autocomplete input field where you can search for items. On selecting an item from the search results, an action is dispatched which triggers a saga.
2. In the saga an API call is made to fetch additional information about the item.
3. After the API call is completed, an action is dispatched which sets the `initialValues` prop of the redux-form used inside the modal.
4. Then another action is dispatched to open the modal.

**Other observations**

1. Removing fields/components from the form inside the modal makes it open faster (~5-6 seconds as compared to ~30 seconds). However, no specific component appears to be at fault because removing any one component has the same effect as removing any other component.
2. In Chrome it takes upto 30 seconds to open but in Firefox it takes upto 5-6 seconds.
3. Dispatching the action to open the modal before dispatching the action which sets the initialValues of the redux-form also makes it open much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some thoughts to look at about reducing the loading time:

1. Try implementing lazy loading from the backend to load potions
   of data.
2. Track the time spent for the API calls in the Network
   tab, so you will see which requests take the longest time.
   Also you can use console.time()/timeEnd() to track the time from inside the code.
3. Different browsers use different engines (i.e. Chrome V8 for Chrome) and can have different priorities of loading data.